# XSLT 1.0: Key based on a whitespace separated attribute

Tags: xslt-1.0, exslt

I have an XML containing elements `a` with an attribute `@ref` that contains at least one pointer and MAY contain any number of pointers separated by whitespaces: `<a ref="#p1 #p2"/>`. In an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet, I need to apply a template to all and only those elements `b` referenced in an `a/@ref` within the document.

So, I thought the idea would be to define a `<xsl:key name="k1" match="a" use="my:refs(@ref)"/>` with a function splitting the value of `@ref` into its constituents and then have a `<xsl:template match="b[key('k1', @xml:id)]"/>`. If I interpret the specs correctly:

> The use attribute is an expression specifying the values of the key; the 
>   expression is evaluated once for each node that matches the pattern. If the 
>   result is a node-set, then for each node in the node-set, the node that 
>   matches the pattern has a key of the specified name whose value is the 
>   string-value of the node in the node-set;

I need to provide a function to `@use` that returns a `node-set` consisting of the values of `a/@ref` (minus the leading '#') as a string.

My solution was to define `<xsl:key name="k1" match="a" use="str:tokenize(@ref, '# ')/>` and `<xsl:template match="a[key('k1', @xml:id)">`.

When I use Xalan as processor, this gives me the wanted result. <del>Saxon 9.6.0.7, however, complains about a circular key definition.</del>

Now I am a bit confused: is my solution valid at all?  <del>and if so, why is Saxon complaining?</del> Are there other/better(/real) solutions? [see comments].

*Edit:* Additional question: How would I get my result in XSLT 2.0? Simply using `tokenize(@ref, '#')` in the key definition is not enough because of the whitespaces while for `normalize-space(tokenize(@ref, '#'))` Saxon will give the same error XTDE0640.

Thanks,
Dario

---

example XML:

```
<root>
    <b xml:id="#p1">P1</b>
    <b xml:id="#p2">P2</b>
    <b xml:id="#pn">Pn</b>
    <a ref="#p2" />
    <a ref="#p1 #pn" />
</root>
```

The output should be

```
P1
P2
Pn
```

(no particular order required).

Comment: I don't think Saxon 9 supports the `str:tokenize()` function. Doesn't need to, as XSLT 2.0 has its own `tokenize()`  function.

Comment: Ah, indeed. Yet, the error message is a bit misleading, isn't it, as the definition isn't really circular but rather contains an unknown function.

Comment: Re your additional question: Your problem cannot be reproduced from the given code: http://xsltransform.net/jyRYYjh Note that the separator I used is a space, not `#` - but even if I change that, there is no error.